# Issue related to using Android attribute (attr) defined in other aar package

Tags: android, aar, declare-styleable

Assume an `attr` is defined in `aar` package (`com.pack1`) as

```
<attr name="attr0" format="string" />
```

and in another package (say `com.pack2` which has dependency on `com.pack1`) I define an `styleable` as

```
<attr name="attr2" format="integer" />
<declare-styleable name="view2">
    <attr name="attr1" format="string" />
    <attr name="attr2" />
</declare-styleable>
```

and I have a custom view in `com.pack2` as

```
public class View2 extends LinearLayout
{
    public View2(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)
    {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.view2, this);
        try
        {
            TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.view2);
            {
                if (typedArray.hasValue(R.styleable.view2_attr1))
                {
                    String t = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.view2_attr1);
                    logger.debug("attr1 -> has value -> {}", t);
                }
                else
                    logger.debug("attr1 -> no value");
                if (typedArray.hasValue(R.styleable.view2_attr2))
                {
                    int t = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.view2_attr2, 0);
                    logger.debug("attr2 -> has value -> {}", t);
                }
                else
                    logger.debug("attr2 -> no value");
            }
            typedArray.recycle();
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            logger.debug(t.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And I add the custom view to a layout as

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.pack2.View2
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:attr1="this is a test"
        custom:attr2="1000"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Up to here when I run the app everything works fine and the logger reports that

```
attr1 -> has value -> this is a test
attr2 -> has value -> 1000
```

but as soon as I change the `styleable` as

```
<attr name="attr2" format="integer" />
<declare-styleable name="view2">
    <attr name="attr0" />
    <attr name="attr1" format="string" />
    <attr name="attr2" />
</declare-styleable>
```

and run the app I receive wrong results. The logger reports that

```
attr1 -> no value
```

and an exception occurred

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to integer: type=0x3
```

It sounds like the value **"This is a test"** is consumed for `attr0` although that attribute is not defined in layout. Note that app gets compiled correctly but the result is wrong.

Why do I receive that result?